# OCR Application which reads text on the go

Tags: ocr, google-translate

Is there any mobile app which reads texts on the go. For an example, google translator app has the camera feature and if the "instant" is on, there's no need to get a pic, rather it will translate the words within the range. But if we keep moving the phone, it will not read out the text which the camera is pointing at. So my question is, Is there any app that performs OCR as the phone is moving, (may be analyzing a video input)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are apps like that. Usually they cover a specific use case.

You mentioned WordTranslate, for translating the text from the camera.
Another one is [Photomath](https://photomath.net), which scans the math problems in real time and outputs the result on screen.
There is also [Windfall](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/windfall-save-money-after/id945543097?mt=8), which can capture the data from the receipts in real time. There are other apps as well - for scanning payment information from invoices, for scanning cheques, etc.

There are also SDKs which can be included in any application which requires such functionality. PhotoMath and Windfall use [BlinkOCR](https://github.com/BlinkOCR) SDK. BlinkOCR is used to start the video input, to perform the OCR on video frames, and return the OCR results.

In the repositories ([iOS](https://github.com/BlinkOCR/blinkocr-ios), [Android](https://github.com/BlinkOCR/blinkocr-android#directAPI)) there are demo apps which you can compile to see BlinkOCR functionality in general use case.

If the use case for the app is really specific (such as scanning math problems, or scanning receipts), then the OCR parameters can be tweaked so you can get very low error rate in the OCR process.

Note: I work for MicroBlink which develops BlinkOCR.